# Merge dataframes by higher level columns

Tags: pandas

I'm trying to merge two dataframes together, as in the image below. The "`Close`" for AMZN and UBER should be merged under the "`Close`" of AAPL, FORD, MSFT; and likewise for all the other higher level cols (`Dividends`, `High`, etc.), they should be merged according to these higher level columns.

I've tried `concat` and then `groupby` these higher level cols, but I think that's just wrong:

```
com = pd.concat([data, data2], axis=1).groupby(['Close', 'Dividends', 'High', 'Low', 'Open', 'Volume'], axis=1)
```

[image]

Comment: ooohh the second one works! thanks jezrael. put that on as an answer and i'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) by `axis=1` for sorting `MultiIndex in columns`:

```
com = pd.concat([data, data2], axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you! I can only accept the answer after 10 mins! Will do so in a bit. why does sort_index group the multiindex? Would've thought it would just do a sort

Comment: @lionbigcat - No, it not index, `concat` add new data to last columns and `sort_index` is for sorting. Sorting is necessary for next processing MultiIndex, [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/advanced.html#sorting-a-multiindex)